# HSQLDB over JDBC: execute SQL statements in batch

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, hsqldb

I need to initialize a database from my Java application. For reasons of code maintainability, I would like to maintain the SQL code separately from the Java code (it is currently in a separate source file).

The first few lines of the file are as follows:

```
-- 1 - Countries - COUNTRIES.DAT;
drop table Countries if exists;
create table Countries(
  CID integer,
  ECC varchar(2),
  CCD varchar(1),
  NAME varchar(50));
```

I read the SQL code from the file and store it in a string. Then I do:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = dbConnection.prepareStatement(sqlString);
```

This fails with the following exception:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected token: CREATE : line: 2
```

This looks as if JDBC doesn't like multiple SQL statements in a single `PreparedStatement`. I have also tried `CallableStatement` and `prepareCall()`, with the same result.

Does JDBC provide a way to pass the entire SQL script in one go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JDBC standard (and the SQL standard for that matter) assumes a single statement per execute. Some drivers have an option to allow execution of multiple statements in one execute, but technically that option violates the JDBC standard. There is nothing in JDBC itself that supports multi-statement script execution.

You need to separate the statements yourself (on the `;`), and execute them individually, or find a third-party tool that does this for you (eg MyBatis `ScriptRunner`).

You might also want to look at something like flyway or liquibase.

Answer (score 0):

To run a hardcoded / loaded from file queries you can use [execute](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#execute(java.lang.String)) like:

```
Statement stmt = null;
String query = "drop table Countries if exists;
                create table Countries(
                      CID integer,
                      ECC varchar(2),
                      CCD varchar(1),
                      NAME varchar(50));";
try {
    stmt = con.createStatement();
    stmt.execute(query);
} catch (SQLException e ) {
    JDBCTutorialUtilities.printSQLException(e);
} finally {
    if (stmt != null) { stmt.close(); }
}
```

If you want to run dynamic queries for example to append values you have to use PreparedStatement. For running a query from a file it's not recommended to put dynamic queries in it.

Comment: This will not work on most databases as JDBC expects a single statement per execute (and most drivers follow that rule, with an explicit config option to violate the spec).